# Compare a certain lines from multiple documents

Tags: bash, scripting, diff, comm

I want to compare a certain lines in a multiple documents. I tried using diff and comm, but the conditions are these,

1. the documents are in a different working directory/folder, I could use a wildcard here for example a (*.doc)

   ```
   File 1  ---> /home/user/file1/1.doc
   File 2  ---> /home/user/file2/2.doc
   File 3  ---> /home/user/file3/3.doc
   ```
2. next is to compare a certain lines (2 to 3 lines) from all of the documents (*.doc)

For example I want to get the Line 2(age) and Line 3(gender) of the following docs.

**1.doc**

```
Name: abc
Age: 123
Gender: m
Contact No.: 222 2222
```

**2.doc**

```
Name: bca
Age: 321
Gender: F
Contact No.: 333 3333
```

**3.doc**

```
Name: bca
Age: 321
Gender: F
Contact No.: 333 3333
```

3. lastly is to generate that lines as another file whether they are the same or with difference.

Comment: Do you want to know if at least one of them differs, or if all of them are different?

Comment: my main purpose is to get the lines 2 and 3. and generate a new file containing the text in that lines. whether they differ or not doesnt matter.

Comment: If you don't care whether they differ, why are you asking about "comparing"? What is your point 3 then? Also, where are these files? Your point 1 is not clear. Please [edit] and clarify. You need to give us all information we need in order to test our solutions. You also need to show your desired output. Finally, are these actually `.doc` files? If so, `diff` won't work on them.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand from your question, you just want to get the lines 2 and 3 from every file and output it into a new file. Here is a script to do so:

```
find . -name "*.doc" | xargs awk 'FNR==2||FNR==3{print}' > new_file
```

`xargs` will make `awk` process every file output by `find`. `awk` will print lines 2 and 3 from every new file it is supplied.

In case the paths may have spaces in it:

```
find . -name "*.doc" -print0 | xargs -0 awk 'FNR==2||FNR==3{print}' > new_file
```

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted to do. but im having a hard time because the *.doc are in different directories/folder

Comment: You can use `find`.

Comment: Does the path have spaces in it?

Comment: no space for the path. example is /home/user/marco/main1/1.doc

Comment: Well, now it works either way, was that that you wanted?

Comment: This will print line 2,3,102,10003,32 and any other line number containing a `2` or a `3`. Use `FNR==2 || FNR==3` instead.

Comment: You are completely right, I've updated the answer already. Coffee didn't kick in yet.